# Limits of integration when transforming from Cartesian to Polar coordinates

Tags: integration, transformation, polar-coordinates

I am asked to evaluate the following integral
[image: question]

The diagram at the bottom left shows how I thought about the integral.
The diagram at the bottom right shows the correct region of integration.

Could you explain where I am going wrong? Why does the region suddenly stop at the y-axis?
In addition, how is it known that the circle cuts the y and x axis at 1? Surely the intercepts are defined by the radius, a, which is not yet defined?

Comment: The very first integral sign in your document has the lower limit $0$, hence indeed the domain of integration is included in the half plane $x>0$.

Comment: Ok thank you, and do you know why the x intercept is at (1,0) and the y intercept is at (0,1)?

Comment: Actually these intercepts are at (a,0) and (0,a).